# Apply a ranged contextual filter to a date in Views

Tags: views, 8

I have an entity with a timestamp field that I would like to filter based on date. I can add a standard filter "between two date", type in two dates, and everything works great. However, contextual ranges do not work. I've read online that Drupal 7 allowed 2016-01-10--2017-01-01 or 20160101--20170101 as input and would display all results in 2016. These do not seem to work in Drupal 8. Is there a way to do range contextual filters in D8?

I've tried using a datetime field instead of a timestamp, and I am unable to filter this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Views Contextual Range Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter/releases/8.x-1.0-beta3) might do the trick for you. Install the latest beta and then see if you need to apply [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2856157-9.patch). It's got just the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I saw this, but the 'releases' list does not show the 8.x version, so I assumed there was none.

Comment: I noticed that. I thought it was too useful a module not to have something in the works for D8 so I checked the repository.

Comment: Unfortunately is doesn't install. The code is probably based on the beta versions of D8.

Comment: This module has been updated and now function for D8.4